# try to update sequence_nbr of table com_sequence table but fail with error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I try to update `sequence_nbr` of table `com_sequence` with max(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 9, 6))) +1 but got error.

```
UPDATE com_sequence_bck 
SET sequence_nbr = MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 9, 6))) + 1  
WHERE (sequence_nbr, rtl_loc_id, wkstn_id,sequence_id) IN
          (SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 9, 6))), SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 3, 3), TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 7, 2)), t.sequence_id  
           FROM com_sequence_bck t, cat_cust_acct C 
           WHERE SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 3, 3) = t.rtl_loc_id 
             AND SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 7, 2) = t.wkstn_id 
             AND t.sequence_id = c.cust_acct_code
           GROUP BY MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 9, 6))), SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 3, 3), SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 7, 2), t.sequence_id        
           ORDER BY register_cat);
```

> Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 42
> Error report
> SQL Error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
> 00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I want to update `sequence_nbr`

Comment: It is impossible to use a group function in the GROUP BY section of a query. It would suffice only GROUP BY t.sequence_id.  Also, it simply makes no sense having an order by in a select in a subquery. To me it looks like bad database/application design having to perform such an update as you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `MAX` in the `GROUP BY` clause and in the outer query, when you do `WHERE (sequence_nbr, ...) IN (SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 9, 6))), ...)` then the `sequence_nbr` in the outer query will be equal to the maximum from the inner query so all you need to do is add 1 to the outer value (you don't have to use `MAX` again).

```sql
UPDATE com_sequence_bck 
SET   sequence_nbr = sequence_nbr + 1  
WHERE (sequence_nbr, rtl_loc_id, wkstn_id,sequence_id) IN (
        SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 9, 6))),
               SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 3, 3),
               TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 7, 2)),
               t.sequence_id  
        FROM   com_sequence_bck t
               INNER JOIN cat_cust_acct c
               ON (   SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 3, 3) = t.rtl_loc_id 
                  AND SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 7, 2) = t.wkstn_id 
                  AND c.cust_acct_code             = t.sequence_id
                  )
        GROUP BY
               SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 3, 3),
               SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 7, 2),
               t.sequence_id
      );
```

Or, more simply:

```sql
UPDATE com_sequence_bck 
SET   sequence_nbr = sequence_nbr + 1  
WHERE (sequence_nbr, rtl_loc_id, wkstn_id,sequence_id) IN (
        SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 9, 6))),
               SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 3, 3),
               TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 7, 2)),
               cust_acct_code
        FROM   cat_cust_acct
        GROUP BY
               SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 3, 3),
               SUBSTR(cust_acct_id, 7, 2),
               cust_acct_code
      );
```

Comment: sorry u writes sql script by assuming there is one max value, but I have max value for each store and each register..

Comment: @user45498 I have made no such assumption. The `GROUP BY` clause means that there will be multiple groups and it will find the maximum for each of those groups. If there is a problem with this then **YOU** need to [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76818602/edit) and provide a [MRE] with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data and the expected output for that sample data rather than blaming the people trying to help you for not understanding something that you have not explained properly.

Answer (score 0):

`"ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here"` is because you're attempting to use an aggregate function `MAX` in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement. Aggregate functions like `MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG` etc. are not allowed to be used directly in the `SET` clause of the `UPDATE statement. you can do this by using a subquery to get the value first.

you can rewrite your SQL statement as below ,

```
UPDATE com_sequence_bck t1
SET sequence_nbr = (
    SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(c.cust_acct_id, 9, 6))) + 1
    FROM cat_cust_acct C 
    WHERE SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 3, 3) = t1.rtl_loc_id 
      AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 7, 2)) = t1.wkstn_id 
      AND t1.sequence_id = c.cust_acct_code
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cat_cust_acct C 
    WHERE SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 3, 3) = t1.rtl_loc_id 
      AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(C.cust_acct_id, 7, 2)) = t1.wkstn_id 
      AND t1.sequence_id = c.cust_acct_code
);
```